# Merging rows pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df =pd.DataFrame([[0,10,0,'A','A',6,7],[11,21,1,'A','A',8,9],[0,13,1,'B','B',11,13],[0,12,1,'C','C',14,15],[13,14,0,'C','C',16,18]],columns=['Start Sample','End Sample','Value','Start Name','End Name','Start Time','End Time'])

df
Out[18]: 
   Start Sample  End Sample  Value Start Name End Name  Start Time  End Time
0             0          10      0          A        A           6         7
1            11          21      1          A        A           8         9
2             0          13      1          B        B          11        13
3             0          12      1          C        C          14        15
4            13          14      0          C        C          16        18
```

I would like to group consecutive rows having the same `Value` if the difference between Start Time of row `i+1` and End Time of row `i` is `< 3`

For example rows 1,2,3 are consecutive rows having the same value.

```
df['Start Time'].iloc[2] - df['End Time'].iloc[1] is = 2
df['Start Time'].iloc[3] - df['End Time'].iloc[2] is = 1
```

So they all should be merged.
I would like that these rows become:

```
df2
Out[25]: 
   Start Sample  End Sample  Value Start Name End Name  Start Time  End Time
0             0          10      0          A        A           6         7
1            11          12      1          A        C           8        15
2            13          14      0          C        C          16        18
```

Please note that the new merged row should have:

```
1) Start Sample = to the Start Sample of the first row merged
2) End Sample = to the End Sample of the last row merged
3) Value = to the common value
4) Start Name = to the Start Name of the first row merged
5) End Name = to the End Name of the last row merged
6) Start Time = to the Start Name of the first row merged
7) End Name = to the End Name of the last row merged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some code for you to consider then some explanation.  The approach here is to break into subsets based on your "Value" and work on those sub-dataframes.

```
def agg(series):
    if series.name.startswith('Start'):
        return series.iloc[0]
    return series.iloc[-1]

subsets = [subset.apply(agg) for _, subset in 
             df.groupby((df['Value']!=df['Value'].shift(1)).cumsum())]

pd.concat(subsets, axis=1).T
```

The "tricky" part is `df['Value']!=df['Value'].shift(1)).cumsum()`.  This finds when the "Value" changes.  We will groupby that but first the `cumsum()` gives the unique values.

After the `groupby`, you are iterating through the subsets of dataframes you are interested in.  From here you can do a great many things which is why this is flexible.

For each subset, the `apply` function will apply to each series (column). In your case, you are looking for one of two values based on the column name so one function (`agg` here) can be applied to each series.

**Edit:** The above test for change only included one of the two criteria OP specified.  Including both is easy enough but extends the logic so it should be broken out a little.  I was already pushing the bounds of an unreasonable oneliner for that logic. so the groupby condition should be:

```
val_chg = df['Value'] != df['Value'].shift(1)
time_chg = df['Start Time']-df['End Time'].shift(1) >=3

df.groupby((val_chg | time_chg).cumsum())
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. But I would like to group rows only if the difference between Start Time of row i+1 and End Time of row i is < 3.. where I can add this condition?

Comment: @gabboshow  oops.  appended an edit with that logic.  Mix and match any booleans to find the change and then groupby the cumsum.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better ways to do it but here is `iterrows()` approach:

```
df =pd.DataFrame([[0,10,0,'A','A',6,7],[11,21,1,'A','A',8,9],[0,13,1,'B','B',11,13],[0,12,1,'C','C',14,15],[13,14,0,'C','C',16,18]],columns=['Start Sample','End Sample','Value','Start Name','End Name','Start Time','End Time'])
df['keep'] = ''

active_row = None

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if active_row is None:
        active_row = i
        df.loc[i,'keep'] = 1
        continue

    if row['Value'] != df.loc[active_row,'Value']:
        active_row = i
        df.loc[i,'keep'] = 1
        continue
    elif row['Start Time'] - df.loc[active_row,'End Time'] >= 3:
        active_row = i
        df.loc[i,'keep'] = 1
        continue

    df.loc[active_row,'End Time'] = row['End Time']
    df.loc[active_row,'End Sample'] = row['End Sample']
    df.loc[active_row,'End Name'] = row['End Name']
    df.loc[i,'keep'] = 0

final_df=df[df.keep == 1].drop('keep',axis=1)
```

It's iterating through rows, remebering the last meaningfull row and updating it during the loop. Each loop classifies a row as keep (1) or not to keep(0), and we use it to manually filter them out by the end.